# Appending Array of data from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a google sheet with a column full of checkboxes. My goal is to have a row of the selected adjacent columns of data (`namedInsured`, `lineCoverage`, etc.) append to a separate sheet when a checkbox is selected and True. This is what I currently have, and it does absolutely nothing.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.range.getSheet();

  var active_range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var namedInsured = ss.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 4).getValue();
  var lineCoverage = ss.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 5).getValue();
  var effDate = ss.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 6).getValue();
  var assignedTo = ss.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 15).getValue();
  var data = [namedInsured, lineCoverage, effDate, assignedTo];

  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");

  if (ss.getName() != "Sheet4" && e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.value == "TRUE") 
  {
    e.source.toast("Quote In Process Entered")
    destinationSheet.appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

[image: This is an example of the sheet I'm referencing]

[This is an example of the desired output][image: 1]
<< If the first and fourth checkboxes were selected one after the other, this is how they should appear on the separate sheet

Comment: Please describe the relevant parts of  your spreadsheet structure and add some sample data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Need logs. Most probably your IF condition fails. Log each of those conditions individually like `console.log(ss.getName() != "Sheet4")` and see if they're as expected.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you, I revised the question with images

Comment: You have an error here `onst destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");` your variable ss is a sheet so there is no getSheetByName() for class Sheet

Comment: Look at the execution logs... there should be an error logged there (see Cooper's comment). P.S. there are a lot of scripts out there that assign a Spreadsheet rather than a Sheet to `ss` but there are a few that assign a Sheet to it... if you are "blending" scripts from differents sources you should put special attention to the variable declarations... and to the execution logs :)

Comment: I cannot thank y'all enough, I finally get to go home. Many, many thanks for your time and effort helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This works for me

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Flag1');
    const [a,b,c] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4,1,3).getValues()[0];
    var d = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 15).getValue();
    var data = [a, b, c, d];
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//modified from original
    dsh.appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: The if statement works fine for me but for whatever reason, I get no output on the separate sheet I'm trying to append data to. I just attempted to use that same formula and I still got no output. Not sure what other steps I need to take, this seems like it should work.

Comment: Read my comment in the other section  your ss.getSheetByName() is not a function because ss is a sheet not a spreadsheet